# Prove security against passive attacks by reduction

Tags: negligible, reduction

I have two private-key encryption ($Π$ and $Θ$) and their concatenation $Π\#Θ$. For example:

$$
Enc_{Π\#Θ}( \ ⟨k_Π, k_Θ⟩, \ ⟨m_Π, m_Θ⟩ \ ) = ⟨ \ Enc_Π(k_Π, m_Π),\ Enc_Θ(k_Θ, m_Θ) \ ⟩; 
$$
(Same for Gen and Dec)

I need to prove that if $Π\#Θ$ is secure against passive adversaries, then both $Π$ and $Θ$ are.

Actually I have proceeded by reduction, so I can prove that: 
$$
Π \ is \ not \ secure \ || \ Θ \ is \ not \ secure \ \Rightarrow \ Π\#Θ \ is \ not \ secure
$$

So I think I can suppose that exist an adversary A that breaks $Π$ (or $Θ$) such that: 
$$
Pr(PrivK_{eat}^{Π,A}(n) = 1) = \frac{1}{2} + ε(n)
$$

 where $ε(n)$ is not negligible.

How can I continue the prove? What should I do now?

Comment: what does it mean to be secure for the concatenation?

Comment: @kelalaka if we build a security scheme that is the concatenation of other two, we have to prove that if one of them two is not secure against passive attacks, then the concatenation of them is not secure against passive attacks

Comment: I usually don't upvote HW questions, though you are fast on editing, nice. You can use any $A$ to distinguish concatenation directly.